# Setting the width of a goog.ui.Textarea

Tags: google-closure

### Context

I'm using goog.ui.textarea from http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_Textarea.html

There is a setMinHeight element, but no setMinWidth element.

In fact, I don't see any type of width setting elements at all.

### Question:

How do I set the initial width/size of a goog.ui.Textarea element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `goog.ui.Textarea` either decorates or renders a `<textarea>` element, the initial width can be controlled using CSS:

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Take a look at the [`goog.ui.Textarea` demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/textarea.html).